# Использовать ли  "use strict"?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Есть ли сейчас смысл использовать выражение "use strict" и какие вкусности он дает?

Comment: Если вы очень хороший JS программист, то нет, не стоит, если не очень хороший - стоит :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope , как запутанно вы ответили.

Comment: @Антон Мухин, ну вот @Spectre написал что у него "почему-то" получается избежать этого самостоятельно, вот ему не стоит заморачиваться, если у вас такие проблемы есть, то `use strict` придет на помощь, лично я использовал раньше, сейчас не практикую (если нет такого требования)

Comment: Это что, на этом и заканчивается действие "use strict"?

Comment: @Антон Мухин, о 'use srtict' -  http://habrahabr.ru/post/118666/ , а использовать или нет вопрос индивидуальный (или, иногда, по требованию)

Comment: нет, хотя никогда не интересовался, вот нагуглил [It’s time to start using JavaScript strict mode](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/)

Comment: Спасибо всем, развеяли мою тьму неведения :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"use strict"` допустим помогает избежать случайного пропуска `new` или `var`, или в таких случаях

```
var func = function(){
    this.value = 'value';
    var a = function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    }
    a();
}
new func();
```

"проблем" с `this`, но почему-то у меня получается избежать этого самостоятельно, возможно потому что изначально поставил за правило использовать `new`, `var`, точки с запятой и не использовать `eval` и `with`